# How to implement a robust plugin system in c# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I prevent the host application from crashing, due to any uncaught exceptions in the instances of a dynamically loaded external DLL?

Right now I have something like the following setup, please note that this is not the exact implementation:

```
internal class ExtensionManager
{
   private static Type mExtension;
   public static GetExtension() { return mExtension; }
   ExtensionManager()
   {
     FileInfo[] fis = null;
     fis = directory.GetFiles("*.dll");
     foreach (FileInfo file in fis)
     {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
       if(some condition)
       {
          mExtension = Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseExtension)));
          break;
       }
     }
   }
}

internal class Room
{

    public Room()
    {
      StartExtensions();
    }
    private BaseExtension CreateInstance(Type classType)
    {
        BaseExtension instance = null;
        try
        {
            instance = (BaseExtension)Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { this });
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            LogException("[Room][CreateInstance()]", error);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void StartExtensions()
    {
        if (!mExtensionInitialised)
        {
            Type classType = ExtensionManager.GetExtension();
            if (classType == null) return;
            if (classType.BaseType != typeof(BaseExtension)) return;
            Task<BaseExtension> task = Task<BaseExtension>.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateInstance(classType), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
               //
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
  static List<Room> mRooms = new List<Room>();
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      Room room = new Room();
      mRooms.Add(room);
    }
  }
}
```

So I need to figure out if there is a uncaught exception, at run-time in the instance created by BaseExtension CreateInstance(Type classType).

P.S .NET Plugin framework is not an option, at the moment for me.

Comment: Use a try/catch for each dll file. not all dll's are .net assemblies.

Comment: `Type mExtension` should be a `List<Type>` i guess

Comment: Create an AppDomain for hosting the plugins.

Comment: Can the moderators open the question? I have edited the original question.